# Trouble Running NVIDIA GPU Containers on Custom Yocto-Based Distro on HPE Server with NVIDIA A40 GPU

Tags: gpu, yocto, containerd, nvidia-docker

I'm experiencing difficulties running NVIDIA GPU containers on a custom Yocto-based distribution tailored for an HPE server equipped with an NVIDIA A40 GPU. Despite having set up a custom [meta-nvidia](https://github.com/kopernikusauto/meta-nvidia) layer (mickledore branch), which includes recipes for NVIDIA drivers, libnvidia-container, libtirpc, and nvidia-container-toolkit (based on meta-tegra's recipes-containers layer at [OE4T/meta-tegra](https://github.com/OE4T/meta-tegra/tree/master/external/virtualization-layer/recipes-containers)), I encounter errors when attempting to run containers that utilize the GPU.

#### Distro Details:

Distro: poky
Included Recipes and Layers: containerd, virtualization layers, NVIDIA drivers and kernel modules, systemd, kernel headers, etc.

## Issue Reproduction Steps:

### Configuring the container runtime:

```
sudo nvidia-ctk runtime configure --runtime=containerd
sudo systemctl restart containerd
```

Pulling images for testing:

```
sudo ctr images pull docker.io/nvidia/cuda:12.0.0-runtime-ubuntu20.04
sudo ctr images pull docker.io/nvidia/cuda:12.0.0-runtime-ubi8
sudo ctr images pull docker.io/nvidia/cuda:12.0.0-base-ubuntu20.04
sudo ctr images pull docker.io/nvidia/cuda:12.0.0-base-ubi8
```

Running a container with GPU:

```
sudo ctr run --rm --gpus 0 --runtime io.containerd.runc.v1 --privileged docker.io/nvidia/cuda:12.0.0-runtime-ubuntu20.04 test nvidia-smi
```

Error Message:

> ctr: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: ldcache error: process /sbin/ldconfig.real failed with error code: 1: unknown

This error persists across all pulled NVIDIA images(non-ubuntu based images show the same error but with `/sbin/ldconfig` instead of `/sbin/ldconfig.real`. However, non-GPU containers (e.g., docker.io/macabees/neofetch:latest) work without issues.
Further Details:

Running `ldconfig -p` shows 264 libs found, including various NVIDIA libraries while running `ldconfig` outputs no error.

`uname -a`: Kernel version: Linux intel-corei7-64-02 6.1.38-intel-pk-standard #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 04:53:52 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Output from `sudo nvidia-container-cli -k -d /dev/tty` info includes warnings about missing libraries and compat32 libraries, although `nvidia-smi` shows the GPU is recognized correctly.

## Attempted Solutions:

Verifying all NVIDIA driver and toolkit components are correctly installed.
Ensuring the ldconfig cache is current and includes paths to the NVIDIA libraries and /sbin/ldconfig.real is a symlink to /sbin/ldconfig.

Despite these efforts, the error persists, and GPU containers fail to start. I'm seeking advice on resolving this ldcache and container initialization error to run NVIDIA GPU containers on this custom Yocto-based distribution.